# Hiding everything of a Gmail account?

Tags: security, google-account

I have a gmail account  and i want to give my account password to someone else who will use it for another app that my gmail account is connected to.
How do i let him use my email and password only for that app and he should not be able to access my gmail mails and google plus account?

Please suggest..Will the 2-Step verification work in this case?

Comment: This is off-topic here but the simple answer is that **you don't give your gmail password to anyone**. Ever. Period. The job of your password is to prove that the person who is logging on is you. Once that person has proven that they are you, they can do anything that you can do, including reading your mail, sending mail in your name and changing your password.

Comment: That doesnt help...i have to give the password and i trust the person i am giving to but i dont want him to see my mails...cant i add another verification for gmail??

Comment: i have a feeling that there should be a way out apart from not giving the password....

Comment: There is no help to give. Sharing your password is the same thing as sharing the power to be you. If you've decided to do that (*decided*; you don't "have to"), you've decided to trust the other person to be you.

Comment: then can i transfer all my emails and stop future emails in my account?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a "guest" account for your Google account. If you give someone your password they'll be able to see everything in your Google account, including the contents of your Gmail.